# Jquery load is not loading properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

i hope somebody can help me.
I have created a lot of plain text apsx pages that will populate different div in a html webpage. im using jquery load function to fetch data into the html page div. The html page is built thru artisteer and the the pages im loading is aspx files. I have issues of using the artisteer layouts so i try to make it "easy" for me to just populate the html page and load different aspx text inte the page.

The pages is working but not loading properly! the page will not load all pages into the div without pushing the refresh button a couple times. Is it a better way to deal with this so all the pages tetx is loaded automatically when the page is loaded the first time.

Please help me!!

```
                               <ol id="result1"></ol>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#result1').load('textpages/firstpage_1_pic.aspx');
</script>
                      </div>

         <o2 id="result2"></o2>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#result2').load('textpages/firstpage_1.aspx');
</script>
```

Comment: what u mean by "not loading properly" ??

Comment: start by using a single script section, and putting your scripts in document.ready()?

Comment: Not loading properly means that sone of the load webpage appear and some dont, But when you push refresh button all the data is there.

Comment: Mike C do you have an example?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your request is completing properly.

```
$("#result1").load("textpages/firstpage_1_pic.aspx", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "An error occured: ";
    alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this message occurred "500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: Thanks for the answers! can this be because that im using aspx c# when loading the text files? Please need your help with this mathers

Comment: A `500` means that something bad happened on the server. There is most likely an exception being thrown in C#.